# Define new symbols and "inverse" function

Tags: function-construction, functional-style, variable-definitions, parametric-functions, variable

I have an expression that involve variables and conjugate of the variables eg

```
exp = a + (b + Abs[ c + I Conjugate[d]^3 ])^2 Conjugate[e] Conjugate[f] + Conjugate[g]
```

Now I want to
a) substitute the conjugates of the variables with new symbols;
b) return to the original expression with an "inverse" substitution.

This is my way to do it:
I can substitute the conjugates of the variables with new symbols in this way

```
AppendConj[x_] := Symbol[ToString[x] <> "Conj"]  

exp1 = exp/. Conjugate[x_] :> AppendConj[x]
```

and I can substitute these new symbols that end with "Conj" with the Conjugate of the symbol in this way:
first I define a function that find the variables in an expression

```
Var[x__] := Union[Cases[Level[x, {-1}], _Symbol]]
```

After

```
exp1 /. Thread[Var[exp1] -> (Var[exp1] /. (x_ :> Conjugate[Symbol[StringDrop[ToString[x], -4]]] /; StringEndsQ[ToString[x], "Conj"]))]
```

The procedure works, but since naming of variables is a very common topic, I think there should be a more elegant way to do it.
How would you do it?

P. S.
I improved what I did before with these substitutions

```
/. Conjugate[y_Symbol] :> Symbol[SymbolName[y] <> "Conj"]  


/. (x_Symbol :> 
   Conjugate[Symbol[StringDrop[SymbolName[x], -4]]] /; 
    StringEndsQ[SymbolName[x], "Conj"])
```

Comment: Do the variables have to be called "aConj" etc?

Comment: @ Feyre
I call them in this way, aConj, bConj, ... but other way to solve the general problem are well accepted ;)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? The thing is: Conjugate[d] and d have a clear relation that Mathematica knows (something) about. If you change the variable names to dConj and d, then this link is broken.

Comment: accept the answer if it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

I normally dislike subscripts, but here it can work well:

```
exp /. Conjugate[x_] :> Subscript[con, x]
%/. Subscript[con, x_] :> Conjugate[x]
```

Comment: Yes, I generally prefer to have `Symbols` instead of `Subscript` too, but anyway it's a fast solutions, thanks :)